# Calculate absolute coordinates in a canvas with panning & zoom

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

How can i calculate a specific position of canvas(e.g. Bottom Center) after changing the viewport position and Zoom Level ?

Right now i am trying something like this. But it only works for viewport.

```
canvasPoint = {
   left:(canvas.width/2)-canvas.viewportTransform[4],
   top: canvas.height-canvas.viewportTransform[5]
}
```

When i **Zoom Out** or **Zoom In**, i am unable to find the new center-bottom point for canvas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use the matrices.
Your bottom - center corner has coordinates:

```
var p = {x: canvas.width/2, y: canvas.height};
```

Your Zoom and Panning is represented by the viewportTransfom:

```
var invertedMatrix = fabric.util.invertTransform(canvas.viewportTransform);
var transformedP = fabric.util.transformPoint(p, invertedMatrix);
```

And you should be done.
transformedP should have the absolutes coordinates of the point that you see as center-bottom in a zoomed and/or panned view.