# Object alignment in fabricJS after zoom and pan

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, canvas, fabricjs

I'm using `fabricJS` with `Angular` when I want to align an element to left for example I'm using the following method

```
alignLeft() {
    // Get Selected Elements
    var obj = this.canvas.getActiveObject();

    // if no element is selected
    if (obj !== undefined) {
      // Bounding Box of the selected element
      var bound = obj.getBoundingRect();

      obj.set('left', (obj.left - bound.left));
      //this.canvas.getActiveObject().setCoords();
      this.canvas.renderAll();
    }
}
```

The alignment works like a charm only then the zoom is in 100%, if I change the zoom or pan the canvas everything goes in the wrong way. Bellow is the methods I use for zooming In/Out

```
this.canvas.on('mouse:wheel', function (opt) {
  var delta = opt.e.deltaY;
  var zoom = this.canvas.getZoom();

  zoom *= 0.999 ** delta;
  if (zoom > 20) zoom = 20;
  if (zoom < 0.01) zoom = 0.01;
  this.canvas.zoomToPoint({ x: opt.e.offsetX, y: opt.e.offsetY }, zoom.toFixed(4));
  opt.e.preventDefault();
  opt.e.stopPropagation();
}.bind(this));

this.canvas.on('mouse:down', function (opt) {
  var evt = opt.e;
  if (evt.altKey === true) {
    this.isDragging = true;
    this.selection = false;
    this.lastPosX = evt.clientX;
    this.lastPosY = evt.clientY;
  }
});

this.canvas.on('mouse:move', function (opt) {
  if (this.isDragging) {
    var e = opt.e;
    var vpt = this.viewportTransform;
    vpt[4] += e.clientX - this.lastPosX;
    vpt[5] += e.clientY - this.lastPosY;
    this.requestRenderAll();
    this.lastPosX = e.clientX;
    this.lastPosY = e.clientY;
  }
});

this.canvas.on('mouse:up', function (opt) {
  // on mouse up we want to recalculate new interaction
  // for all objects, so we call setViewportTransform
  this.setViewportTransform(this.viewportTransform);
  this.isDragging = false;
  this.selection = true;
});
```

After I read [multiple questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36401107/calculate-absolute-coordinates-in-a-canvas-with-panning-zoom) and the [fabricJS Documentation](http://fabricjs.com/using-transformations) I changed the `alignLeft()` method to the following:

```
alignLeft() {
    // Get Selected Elements
    var obj = this.canvas.getActiveObject();

    // if no element is selected
    if (obj !== undefined) {
      // Bounding Box of the selected element
      var bound = obj.getBoundingRect();
      let p = {x: (obj.width / 2), y: obj.top}
      var invertedMatrix = fabric.util.invertTransform(this.canvas.viewportTransform);
      let newp = fabric.util.transformPoint(p, invertedMatrix);

      obj.set('left', newp.x);
      //this.canvas.getActiveObject().setCoords();
      this.canvas.renderAll();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to user `ViewPortCoordinates` (see [fabricJS Docs](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Canvas.html#vptCoords)) to get `top left`, `top right`, `bottom left`, `bottom right` coordinates of the `canvas` according the the view port.

> Describe canvas element extension over design properties are tl,tr,bl,br. if canvas is not zoomed/panned those points are the four corner of canvas if canvas is viewportTransformed you those points indicate the extension of canvas element in plain untrasformed coordinates The coordinates get updated with @method calcViewportBoundaries.

for `alignLeft()` method you can update it to the following:

```
alignLeft() {
    // Get Selected Elements
    var obj = this.canvas.getActiveObject();

    // if no element is selected
    if (obj !== undefined) {
        const viwePortCoords = this.canvas.vptCoords;
        obj.set('left', viwePortCoords.bl.x + (obj.width / 2));

        this.canvas.renderAll();
    }
    this.canvas.fire('object:modified', { target: obj });
}
```